# Detecting eye blinking algorithms

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have implemented face detection on my application using [this](https://blog.grijjy.com/2017/09/11/face-detection-on-android-and-ios/) guide.
And i want to add eye blinking detection to it now. unfortunately there is no detailed properties in the Face Detector about eye blinking in Android.
The solution I thought about is  : count the percentage of black color (iris) in both eye `Rects` drawn in the Paintbox, if that is possible, more black color means the eye is open and less black color means eye is closed.
I'm not sure how to implement that. As there is no way i know to get the color parameters from Paintbox.

here is the code if Painting :

```
procedure TCameraView.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
  var
    SrcRect, DstRect, Rect: TRectF;
    Scale, DstWidth, DstHeight: Single;
    Face: TgoFace;

    procedure PaintEye(const APosition: TPointF; const AColor: TAlphaColor);
    var
      P: TPointF;
      R: TRectF;
      Radius: Single;
    begin
    try
      { Exit if eye position is not available }
      if (APosition.X = 0) and (APosition.Y = 0) then
        Exit;

      P.X := APosition.X * Scale;
      P.Y := APosition.Y * Scale;
      P.Offset(DstRect.TopLeft);

      Radius := Face.EyesDistance * Scale * 0.2;
      R := RectF(P.X - Radius, P.Y - Radius, P.X + Radius, P.Y + Radius);
      Canvas.Stroke.Color := AColor;
      Canvas.DrawEllipse(R, 1);
      Except on E  :Exception do
      begin
    // ShowMessage(e.Message);
      end;
      end;
    end;

  begin
  try
    { Paint bitmap to fit the paint box while preserving aspect ratio. }
    SrcRect := RectF(0, 0, FBitmap.Width, FBitmap.Height);
    Scale := Min(PaintBox1.Width / FBitmap.Width, PaintBox1.Height / FBitmap.Height);
    DstWidth := Round(FBitmap.Width * Scale);
    DstHeight := Round(FBitmap.Height * Scale);
    DstRect.Left := Floor(0.5 * (PaintBox1.Width - DstWidth));
    DstRect.Top := Floor(0.5 * (PaintBox1.Height - DstHeight));
    DstRect.Width := DstWidth;
    DstRect.Height := DstHeight;
    Canvas.DrawBitmap(FBitmap, SrcRect, DstRect, 1);

    Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 2;

    { Paint each face with its features }
    for Face in FFaces do
    begin
      { Paint bounds around entire face }
      Rect := Face.Bounds;
      Rect.Left := Floor(Rect.Left * Scale);
      Rect.Top := Floor(Rect.Top * Scale);
      Rect.Right := Ceil(Rect.Right * Scale);
      Rect.Bottom := Ceil(Rect.Bottom * Scale);
      Rect.Offset(DstRect.TopLeft);

      Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Lime;
      Canvas.DrawRect(Rect, 4, 4, AllCorners, 1);

      { Paint the eyes }
      PaintEye(Face.LeftEyePosition, TAlphaColors.Magenta);
      PaintEye(Face.RightEyePosition, TAlphaColors.Cyan);
    end;
     Except on E  :Exception do
      begin
     // ShowMessagE(E.message);
      end;
      end;
  end;
```

Comment: A bit off topic, but still: You should remove your `try..except` blocks. Even without those, you will get notified by the error, so you don't need these blocks to be notified. However, these blocks aren't only unnecessary: they are also harmful, since they make execution *continue* after an exception.

Comment: Trying to detect closed / open eyes may be difficult since the frame rate of the camera may not even be fast enough to pick it up or there may be motion blur issues. Why not instead try to detect rapid changes in the image localised around the position of the eyes. A high rate of change in those areas and not surrounding areas indicates a blink. This could also be done without colour info. Your suggestion may also fail for people with dark skin.

Comment: Thanks you for the advice, it's not easy to detect rapid changes in image, i don't even know where to begin with. @XylemFlow

Comment: In each frame store bitmaps for each eye centred at the eye positions with a given width and height of the expected size of the eye area. Then compare them to the same set of images from the previous frame by taking an absolute difference of each pixel. Any large values in the resulting difference indicates high rate of change. If you get high values in both eyes at once then you detect a blink. In Delphi FMX you can get fast access to the pixel data using TBitmapData.